# Notepad++ and sFTP Support

Tags: notepad++, sftp

Anyone knows of a sFTP plugin for Notepad++ ? I just checked FTP_syncrhonize and it doesnt support sFTP. (please no "use filezilla/winscp/putty" answers).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Do have a look at [NppFTP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/)

> Plugin for Notepad++ allowing FTP,
>   FTPS, FTPES and **SFTP** communications.

Comment: Wow. This is huge! Why doesn't this answer and question have 500 votes! I mean I love ssh-ing in and using Emacs, but Notepad++ and sftp is sweet!

Comment: Have problem with private key authentication, although my key works in `winscp`. Key agent does not work either. The plugin seems to be a bit outdated.

Comment: For those who need some help configuring it (or are simply as lazy as me! :-D), I've found this guide good: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-ftp-with-notepad/